# Get variable of a controller with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

i try to get a result of a variable of a controller , like this :

```
$('#ajax-test').click(function() {
     $.get('/ajax', function(data) {
      $('#ajax-test').html('$result').html(data);
     });
});
```

i have only errors, so what is the correct way ?

Comment: What is `$result` doing there? Your question is rather vague. If data is html then just `$('#ajax-test').html(data)` or `$('#ajax-test').load('/ajax')`

Comment: oh sorry, $result is the variable in my controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get value from the controller variable. You should have to specify the code as follow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#ajax-test').click(function() {
        $.get('/ajax', function(data) { // no action specified so index will default.
          $('#ajax-test').html('$result').html(data);
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

and in your controller.

```
public function index(){
   $this->layout = null; // layout not required.
   $this->autoRender = false; // view file is also not required.

   // other statements.
   echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to get the value of your controller just make your controller echo or display the the result:

```
 public function ajax() {
     echo $result;
 }
```

so that the function(data) will get the function value automatically.

if you really want to get the value including the variable then put your values in an array put it in json and parse it in your jquery:

```
 public function ajax() {
     $array['result'] = 'hello world'; // where result is your variable name
     echo json_encode($array);
 }
```

Comment: But if i have others variable ? i search the way to directly get a variable.

Comment: @YoPlait what Vainglory07 is saying is that you need to have whatever function is responding to the Ajax call echo, render, or return (pick your terminology) the value you want back in the response, which will be given to you once the request is incomplete in the `data` variable inside your Ajax success function. What you asked directly doesn't make sense, since once the page has been loaded, any variables set from the previous request don't exist any more. You can't directly access a variable in the manner you're thinking; your server basically needs to "respond" with the value you want.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I just realized I have a typo: "once the request is incomplete" should be "once the request is complete".